# Add prefix to line that is the pattern of text after dot using sed or other command

Tags: sed

I am trying to edit linux file using sed or other command.

This is my File t:

```
first.xlsx
second.txt
third.ksh
```

I want to change File t to be:

```
xlsx/first.xlsx
txt/second.txt
ksh/third.ksh
```

So text after the dot should be added to start of line followed by a forward slash.

What is sed or other command I can use to make this change?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and then [edit] your question to format your input, output, and code as Text Blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this change with

```
sed 's|.*\.\(.*\)|\1/&|'
```

which uses `|` as the delimiter,
so we can use `/` as a literal character without escaping it. 
To change the file `t` in place, use

```
sed -i 's|.*\.\(.*\)|\1/&|' t
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works like a charm.

Updated file t after running sed -i 's|.*\.\(.*\)|\1/&|' t:
xlsx/first.xlsx
txt/second.txt
ksh/third.ksh

Comment: Beware that assumes the text is encoded as per the locale's charmap. On the output of `printf 'St\351phane.Chazelas.R\351sum\351.pdf\n'` (which is `Stéphane.Chazelas.Résumé.pdf` but encoded in iso8859-1), and in a UTF-8 locale, you'd get `St$'\351'R/phane.Chazelas.R$'\351'sum$'\351'.pdf` (at least with GNU `sed`). You could run that under `LC_ALL=C` to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` instead of `sed`:

```bsh
awk -F . '{ printf "%s/%s\n", $NF, $0 }' file
```

or, using `/` as the output field separator,

```bsh
awk -F . -v OFS=/ '{ print $NF, $0 }' file
```

These treat `.` as a field delimiter and output the last such field (`$NF`) followed by a slash and the original line (`$0`).

With a recent release of GNU `awk`, you could make the modification to the file in-place using

```bsh
awk -i inplace -F . '{ printf "%s/%s\n", $NF, $0 }' file
```